# Uri permission is not granted to a path of provider

Tags: java, android, permissions

I have a provider in my app

```
<provider android:authorities="com.myapp.android.provider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.myapp.android.provider.FileSystemProvider">
    <grant-uri-permission android:pathPrefix="/"/>
</provider>
```

And when I call the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.myapp.android.CameraActivity");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.myapp.android.provider/"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
        | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I get exception

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting
>   Intent { dat=content://com.myapp.android.provider/ flg=0xc3
>   cmp=com......../com......... (has extras) } from
>   ProcessRecord{44955bc0 9477:com...../u0a260} (pid=9477,
>   uid=10260) not exported from uid 10261

What I do wrong? I tried to specify full path to a file or different directory, but it never worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
intent.setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.myapp.android.CameraActivity");
```

Most likely, this is not the actual line of code that is in your app; your real code is specifying some other app. Regardless, this component is not exported, and therefore you cannot access it from your app.

Comment: But why? I granted the access

Comment: Android docs say: `If a content provider's grantUriPermissions attribute is "true", permission can be granted for any the data under the provider's purview. However, if that attribute is "false", permission can be granted only to data subsets that are specified by this element. A provider can contain any number of <grant-uri-permission> elements. Each one can specify only one path (only one of the three possible attributes).`

Comment: @SteveWarner: You granted access to a `Uri`. The activity is in somebody else's app, and that activity is not exported.

Comment: But I granted it to rather app than mine. So I expect it to be not exported to anyone, but my other app should have access by the specified uri

Comment: @SteveWarner: The activity that you are trying to start is in somebody else's app. You did not write the activity. The developers of the other app have not exported the activity that you are trying to start.

Comment: My fault, I'm a developer of the second one app. Exported it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <provider android:authorities="com.myapp.android.provider" 
android:exported="true"<----- change android:name="com.myapp.android.provider.FileSystemProvider">
        <grant-uri-permission android:pathPrefix="/"/>
    </provider>
```

Comment: I want to keep it not exported to anyone. Just grant specific paths